# How do I downgrade from Lollipop back to KitKat on htc desire 816

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

How to go back to android kitkat from lollipop in htc desire 816 dual sim?

factory data reset and phone reset in settings, i have tried.

Comment: If this is stock rom, you probably can't.

Answer (score -1):

You would want to look for official stock firmware(Kitkat) provided by HTC, if you find one, you can flash it and get back to Kitkat. At least that's what I did on my Nexus 5.

Comment: This explains that yes, the downgrade can be done. But it doesn't explain the procedure to follow. Assume that OP doesn't know about flashing (no signs in the question) and then re-write your answer. You can quote as well, and avoid link-only answer. :)